# Unable to find workbook ID using python script or F12 network tab for dashboard published on self hosted tableau server

Tags: python, python-3.x, tableau-api

I an trying to find Workbook ID which will alphanumeric from the dashboard I published on self Tableau server behind firewall.

This code works fine and give workbook ID on Tableau cloud (https://prod-apnortheast-a.online.tableau.com) but on our server its gives ouput as No workbook found with name or pattern, even I tried changing code with exact name in exact project still didn't worked.

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import io
import csv
import string
import re
 
# Tableau Server credentials
server = 'server'
token_name = 'name'
personal_access_token = 'token'
SITE_NAME = 'sitename'
PROJECT_NAME = 'product'
WORKBOOK_PATTERN = 'Ads.*'
 
# Tableau Server authentication
server = TSC.Server(server, use_server_version=True)
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(token_name,personal_access_token, SITE_NAME)
 
# Sign in to Tableau Server
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    #all_workbooks_items, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get()
    print('Logged in to source server successfully')
    all_projects, pagination_item = server.projects.get()
 
    project = next((project for project in all_projects if project.name == PROJECT_NAME), None)
 
    if project is None:
        print(f"Project '{PROJECT_NAME}' not found.")
    else:
        project_id = project.id
        print(f"Project ID for '{PROJECT_NAME}': {project_id}")
        print("Searching workbooks under the project...")
 
    # Get all the workbooks
        all_workbooks_items, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get()
 
    # Filter the workbooks by project ID
        matching_workbooks = [workbook for workbook in all_workbooks_items if workbook.project_id == project_id and re.search(WORKBOOK_PATTERN, workbook.name)]
 
        if len(matching_workbooks) == 0:
            print("No workbooks found matching the pattern.")
        else:
            print("Matching Workbooks:")
            for workbook in matching_workbooks:
                print(f"Workbook ID: {workbook.id}, Workbook Name: {workbook.name}")
```

Output:

```
Logged in to source server successfully
Project ID for 'product': lajsad87ijaskta4-asd-8as
Searching workbooks under the project...
No workbooks found matching the pattern.
```

Is this issue with my account access level or is there a different approach to access workbook Id and view id on self hosted tableau server's?